# MySQL Query exceptions

Tags: mysql, records

In one page, it should show records that has the following selected month from the drop down menu and it is set in the ?month=March

So the query will do this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE month = '" . Clean($_GET['month']) . "' AND finished='0' ORDER BY date ASC";
```

But it shows records that has a value of 2 in the finished column and I don't want the query to include this.

I've tried

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE month = '" . Clean($_GET['month']) . "' AND finished='0' OR finished = '1' OR finished = '3' ORDER BY date ASC";
```

But it shows records on different months when it shouldn't be.

So basically I want the record to *exclude* the records that has the value of **2** in the record that will not be shown in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query should do what you want. Rows with `finished = '2'` should not be returned.

Ignoring that there is an error in your second query that you probably should fix:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE month = '" . Clean($_GET['month']) .
       "' AND (finished='0' OR finished = '1' OR finished = '3') ORDER BY date ASC";
```

The difference is parentheses around the OR clauses because AND binds more strongly than OR.

You could also achieve the same result more concisely using `IN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE month = '" . Clean($_GET['month']) .
       "' AND finished IN ('0', '1', '3') ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Comment: Wow, quick answer :) thanks for this, I used your second code

Answer (score 0):

`AND finished='0' OR finished = '1' OR finished = '3'`

to

`AND finished != 2`

or

`AND (finished = 0 OR finished = 1 OR finished = 3)`